# get correct output for correct click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to put the value from the input into the div depending upon the key that is pressed.
What is wrong with the code and how to correct it.

```
<input id = "mp1" /><input id = "mp2" />
<button id="sum1">Submit1</button>
<button id ="sum2">Submit2</button>
<div id="out"></div>

$('button').click(function() {
    var k = this.id.substr(this.id.length -1);
    var mp = $('#mp'+k).value;
    $('#out').html (mp);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ftE36/1/

Comment: i dont see any key press handling
did you mean different value upon the click of different button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either use [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/):

```
document.getElementById('mp'+k).value;
```

Or jQuery:

```
$("#mp"+k).val();
```

Avoid mix-and-match ;)

Comment: on a completely irrelevant note, that vanilla js site is simple awesome :D

Comment: Thanks I just started using JQuery recently, forgot to add the brackets after the value.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, i think you want something like this:

```
$('button').click(function(e) {

    var k = e.target.id.substr(this.id.length -1);
    var mp = $('#mp'+k).val();

    $('#out').html (mp);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/RM4UQ/

Answer (score 0):

try  something like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mp1").keypress(function () {
            $("#out").html($(this).val());
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code:

**html:**

```
<input id = "mp1" /><input id = "mp2" />
<button id="sum1">Submit1</button>
<button id ="sum2">Submit2</button>
<div id="out"></div>
```

**js:**

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
    //var id = e.target.id;
    
    var k = e.target.id.substr(this.id.length -1);
    var mp = $('#mp'+k).val();
    $('#out').html (mp);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jebasuthan/k927H/)

Hope it should helpful for you. Please try and let me know. Thanks.